# How to add custom button to material date range picker android?

Tags: android, material-components-android

How can I add a custom button to material date range picker?

I'm trying to get view of the dialog so that I can add button programmatically, but I can't get any view from the picker.

```
        MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Pair<Long,Long>> builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker();
        MaterialDatePicker<Pair<Long,Long>> materialDatePicker = builder
            .setTitleText("Select Dates")
            .build();
        dateRangeTV.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            materialDatePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DATE_PICKER");
            View root = materialDatePicker.requireView();
        });
```

But I'm getting error saying.

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment MaterialDatePicker{e52ecfc} (40593b4f-a55a-4d6c-aa3b-2b778e721149 tag=DATE_PICKER) did not return a View from onCreateView() or this was called before onCreateView().`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurred because the `materialDatePicker.show()` is an asynchronous call and the `MaterialDatePicker` (DialogFragment) was not created yet to be able to access its root View. To avoid this error you have to listen for the DialogFragment `Lifecycle` using the `materialDatePicker.getLifecycle()` by adding a `DefaultLifecycleObserver` and use the override method `void onStart(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner)` to access the `MaterialDatePicker` root View from there.

Change your code to be like the below:

```
MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Pair<Long,Long>> builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker();
MaterialDatePicker<Pair<Long,Long>> materialDatePicker = builder
        .setTitleText("Select Dates")
        .build();
materialDatePicker.getLifecycle().addObserver(new DefaultLifecycleObserver()
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner) {}

    @Override
    public void onStart(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner) {
        //in onStart of DialogFragment the View has been created so you can access the materialDatePicker.requireView()
        View root = materialDatePicker.requireView();
        //from root find the View you are interested to add your custom button
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner) {}

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner) {
        //remove Lifecycle Observer
        materialDatePicker.getLifecycle().removeObserver(this);
    }
});
materialDatePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DATE_PICKER");
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example I created a class `MainActivity.java` and it's layout that open a custom Dialog from a `Button` like this:

The `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private Button openDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        openDialog = findViewById(R.id.open_dialog);
        openDialog.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: opening dialog.");
            MyCustomDialog dialog = new MyCustomDialog();
            dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "MyCustomDialog");
        });
    }
}
```

`Layout` with the `Button` `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/open_dialog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
        android:text="open dialog" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the `MyCustomDialog.java` class extends the `DialogFragment` to have a custom View to store the `DatePicker` and also other `Widgets` in it. (e.g. `TextView`):

```
public class MyCustomDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private static final String TAG = "MyCustomDialog";

    private TextView mActionOk, mActionCancel;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_my_custom, container, false);
        mActionCancel = view.findViewById(R.id.action_cancel);
        mActionOk = view.findViewById(R.id.action_ok);

        mActionCancel.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: closing dialog");
            getDialog().dismiss();
        });

        mActionOk.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: capturing input");
            getDialog().dismiss();
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Last but not least the `XML` file `dialog_my_custom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="550dp"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/heading"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:text="This is your custom View with DatePicker"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/date_picker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/heading"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/date_picker">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/action_ok"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:text="OK"
                android:textColor="#33bbff"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/action_cancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:text="CANCEL"
                android:textColor="#33bbff"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Don't forget to add the `dependency` of the support library:

```
implementation  "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibVersion"
```

**RESULT:**

[image: DataPicker in a custom View]

Comment: Sorry, but I want view for the datepicker himself.

Comment: Edited my answer. Here you go :) Now you have your custom View. Hope I could help you. Feel free to tick the answer as correct and most important happy Coding! :)

Comment: Can I get material date range picker in this custom fragment?

Comment: In what view do you want to have this? Your DatePicker is already in your custom view. Did you use my source code? It is all costumized already.